# How disable auto reindex after edit product or catalog

Tags: reindex

I have a problem when in edit catalog, product and save it. My website will reindex, that do my website run very slow. I want to disable reindex after save catalog,product

But when i created new catalog, product other. Website will reindex again

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to `System->index management` and change your indexes mode to 'manual' instead of `on save`.
Do your changes in the catalog and then rebuild the indexes manually.
But this will disable the index on any action you take. Add or edit.
There is no (fast) way of disabling the "on save" index only for editing products.

Comment: I have change mode to manual. But when i click reindex, my system is down

Comment: don't reindex from the backend. Use the command line.